Correlation of random variables in a multivariate hypergeometric scenario
Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N\}$ be a set of $N$ elements and suppose such set is partitioned into $k$ mutually exclusive categories. Take $N_i$ to be the number of elements in the $i$-th category and $y_i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, k-1\}$ to be the category $a_i$ belogns to. Define $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{1, 2, \ldots, N\})$ by
$$
   \mathcal{S} := \{s \in \mathcal{P}(\{1,2, \ldots, N\}) \mid |s| = n\}
   $$
for some fixed integer $0 < n < N$ and let $\mathcal{F}_s := \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{S})$. Assume all elements of $A$ are equally likely to be selected at random. Thus, we can define a probability measure $p$ on the measurable space $(\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{F}_s)$ such that $p(s)$ is constant for all $s \in S$. Suppose we take some subset $\{i_1, \ldots, i_n\} = s$ of $\mathcal{S}$ randomly. Now, we examine the elements of $s$ in order. Let $X_j$, $1 \leq j \leq n$ be a random variable that represent the category of the $j$-th element selected from $s$.
I desire to prove that $X_i$ and $X_j$, $i \neq j$ are not uncorrelated. This situation correponds to a multivariate hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N$ (total number of elements in $A$), $n$ (size of the sample taken from $A$) and $(N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_k)$ (mutually exclusive categories of elements of $A$ such that $N = N_1 + \cdots + N_k$). I´ve got the following:
First, notice that $X_1 \backsim HG(1, N_0, N_1, \ldots, N_{k-1})$. That is, $X$ has a multivariable hypergeometric distribution with parameters $1$ (size of the sample taken from $A$) and $(N_0, N_1, \ldots, N_{k-1})$ (mutually exclusive categories of elements of $A$ such that $N = N_0 + \cdots + N_{k-1}$). We consider $X_1$ to be a measurable function whose image is contained in $\mathbb{N}^{k+1}$ and
$$
  \mathbb{P}(X_1 = (0, \ldots, 0, \underset{(i+1\text{-th entry})}{1}, 0, \ldots, 0))
  $$
to be the probability that $X_1$ comes out to be of the $i$-th category, $i = 0,1, \ldots, k-1$. We also define
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_i = (1, b_1, \ldots, b_k)) = 0
$$
for all $(b_1, \ldots, b_k) \in \{0,1\}^k$ and all $i = 1,2, \ldots, n$.
Provided that we are sampling without replacement, we have that
$$
X_2 \backsim HG((1, N_0, N_1, \ldots, N_{k-1}) - X_1)
$$
In other words, we subtract one element from the category of the first element picked form $s$ because there is no replacement once we have take some element. Analogously, for $3 \leq m \leq n$ we get
$$
X_m \backsim HG\left((1, N_0, N_1, \ldots, N_{k-1}) - \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} X_i\right)
$$
For simplicity, for $m = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ denote $Z_{m} = \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i$ and take $(Z_m)_i$ to be the $i$-th component of $Z_m$. Then, for $i = 0, 1, \ldots k-1$ and $m = 1, 2, \ldots, n$
$$
f_{X_m}(0, \ldots, 0, \underset{(i+1\text{-th entry})}{1}, 0, \ldots, 0) = \frac{N_i - (Z_{m-1})_{i+1}}{N - (m-1)}.
$$
This implies that $X_i$ and $X_j$, $i \neq j$ are not uncorrelated as there is a linear relationship on the $X_i's$.
I can even go futher and find the distribution and mean of the r.v. $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Let $Y_i$, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, represent the number of elements of the category $k$ in a sample of $n$ elements. The random vector $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$ has a multivariate hypergeometric distribution with parameters $n$ (size of the sample taken from $A$) and $(N_0, N_1, \ldots, N_{k-1})$ (mutually exclusive categories of elements of $A$ such that $N = N_1 + \cdots + N_k$). In case $k = 2$ we have a hypergeometric distribution of $Z$ because there are two categories of elements and $Z$ is a random variable that represents the number of elements in a sample of $n$ elements that belong to the category $1$. Concretely, $Z \backsim HG(n, N_0, N_1)$ and $Z$ has a p.d.f. given by
$$
f_Z(x) = \frac{\binom{N_1}{x} \binom{N_0}{n - x}}{\binom{N}{n}}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, \min\{n, N_1\}, \quad n - x \leq N_0.
$$
This implies that
$$
\mathbb{E}(Z) = \frac{nN_1}{N}.
$$
Is the argument correct?

The general idea looks fine to me, but the notations are somewhat casual.
